# Por que mis variables POST no se muestran

Tags: javascript, php

Por que mis variables POST no se muestran, pero si veo en el preview y response de la consola si los muestra pero en la pagina web estan vacios.

Aque se debe eso, tiene que ver con mi AJAX?, la vercion de PHP que se esta usando es PHP 5

```
    function mostrarpdf_indicadores (){ 

    var formElement = document.getElementById("frm_dietas");
    var formData = new FormData(formElement);   
 
    var options = {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php?page=progcamas&accion=mostrarpdfindicadores',   
        data: formData,
        processData: false,  
        contentType: false,
    dataType : 'html', 
        success: function(){    
                console.log('Generado ....... !');
                $('#pdf_mostrar').show(); 
                $('#div_loading').hide();    
        }, 
        error: function(){
            console.log ('FUNCION ERROR DEL AJAX: mostrarpdf_indicadores');         
        }
    };
    $.ajax(options);    
};
```

Esta es mi funcion PHP

```
function _mostrarpdfindicadoresAction()
    {   
        $idservicio=$_POST['idservicio'];
        $fecha_pedido=$_POST['fecha_pedido'];
        $id_tipo_racion=$_POST['id_tipo_racion'];
        $a=isset($_POST['usuario']);
        $b=isset($_POST['fecha_pedido']);
        $c=isset($_POST['id_tipo_racion']);

        echo ('ID del servidor: '.$idservicio);
        echo (' - Fecha: '.$fecha_pedido);
        echo (' - ID de la ración: '.$id_tipo_racion);
        echo (' - Rertorna F o V: '.$a);

        var_dump($idservicio);
        var_dump($fecha_pedido);
        var_dump($id_tipo_racion);

        
        var_dump($_POST);
        $d='hola';
        var_dump($d);

    }
```

En lo que es el preview y response de la consola, si se ven los valores que se les asigna

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: agrega `$('#pdf_mostrar').html(response)` arriba de `$('#pdf_mostrar').show();`, saludos.

Comment: Hola, tienes razon; pero ahora tengo un problema con el PDF que en teoria tiene que generarse.
Para el PDF se esta usando FPDF

Comment: Genera otra pregunta.